# PHP Composer in Docker Container doesn't work at MS Azure in Deployment Group

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure, composer

I have deployed the same Docker container which works inside Windows WSL-2, Ubuntu 22.04 and Mac, **to MS Azure**, using command:

```
az group deployment create --resource-group <MyGroup> --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters parameters.json
```

It seemed to work, and it correctly mounts File share from Storage account, where the `composer.json` file is stored, via:

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "dev",
    "azureFile": {
      "shareName": "<MyShareName>",
      "storageAccountName": "<MyStorageName>",
      "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('storageAccountKey')]"
    }
  }
],
```

I can access `BASH` inside the container using:

```
az container exec --resource-group <MyGroup> --name <MyContainerGroup> --container-name <MyContainerName> --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

**However:**

When I run `composer install` from that container, which works inside all the other environments mentioned above, it fails.

Although the `composer.json` file does not contain any private repositories - and as I've written above it works just fine elsewhere - I am getting the following error message on Azure:

```
Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
When working with _public_ GitHub repositories only, head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=&description=Composer+on+SandboxHost-638176962110261340+2023-04-21+1757 to retrieve a token.
This token will have read-only permission for public information only.
```

I have generated the token as suggested, but it made no difference.

Any help is highly appreciated!